# ITextSharp: Change the color of a table cell border

Tags: html, css, itext

I have spent a while trying to research this, but haven't come up with a way to do it.  Basically, I am converting fairly basic dynamic html to a pdf using ITextSharp. In the html, there are a few tables that convert over just fine, but I can't find a way to change the border color.  It just comes out as a solid black.

```
    StyleSheet css = new StyleSheet();
    css.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.TD, HtmlTags.BORDER, "1");
```

That turned on the border, but is there a way to change the border color from black to whatever I want?

Comment: I think is not possible because the property is not decared into HTMLTags at version 5.X
<br />
http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/417/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/html/HtmlTags.cs?force=True